# Display a StackPanel only if one of two options are selected in a radio button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application and one page shows two stack panels with radio buttons in them. I want to have it so that the visibility of the second stack panel is dependent on whether certain radio buttons are selected or not.

```
<Grid Background="#F8FBFD">
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackType" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,93,0,428">
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" >Installation Type</TextBlock>
                <RadioButton Checked="NewMode_Checked" Content="New " x:Name="rbtnNew" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding newMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}"/>
                <RadioButton  Checked="UpgradeMode_Checked" Content="Update" x:Name="rbtnUpgrade" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding upgradeMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}" />
                <RadioButton  Checked="ChangeMode_Checked" Content="Change" x:Name="rbtnChange" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding changeMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackMode" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Visible">
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16" Width="204" Height="147">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" >Installation Mode</TextBlock>
                <RadioButton Content="Default Settings" Name="rbtnDefaultMode" IsChecked="{Binding defaultMode, Source={StaticResource modes}, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="defaultSettings_Checked"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Custom Settings" Name="rbtnCustomMode" IsChecked="{Binding customMode, Source={StaticResource modes}, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="customSettings_Checked"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In this, I want to have it in a way so that if `rbtnNew` or `rbtnUpgrade` are selected, only then should the `StackMode` panel be should be visible. And if `rbtnChange` is selected, the panel `StackMode` panel should stay hidden.

Comment: It looks odd that there are multiple boolean properties in your view model for selecting a single state. Apparently the `mode` state is either `new`,  `upgrade` or `change`, so why are you not using a single enum-type property? You could then bind the Visibility of the second StackPanel to that enum property with an appropriate Binding Converter. You may also find solutions on StackOverflow how to set the enum property by a set of RadioButtons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom style with a `DataTrigger`:

- Remove the `Visibility="Visible"` from the `StackMode` panel.
- Add a `Setter` that sets the default value of `Visibility` of the `StackPanel` to `Visible`.
- Add a `DataTrigger` that sets its value to `Collapsed` (or `Hidden`) if the `IsChecked` value of `rbtnChange` is `true`. You can refer to the element with [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname) in the binding.

```
<Grid Background="#F8FBFD">
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackType" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,93,0,428">
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" >Installation Type</TextBlock>
                <RadioButton Checked="NewMode_Checked" Content="New " x:Name="rbtnNew" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding newMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}"/>
                <RadioButton  Checked="UpgradeMode_Checked" Content="Update" x:Name="rbtnUpgrade" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding upgradeMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}" />
                <RadioButton  Checked="ChangeMode_Checked" Content="Change" x:Name="rbtnChange" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding changeMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackMode" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16" Width="204" Height="147">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" >Installation Mode</TextBlock>
                <RadioButton Content="Default Settings" Name="rbtnDefaultMode" IsChecked="{Binding defaultMode, Source={StaticResource modes}, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="defaultSettings_Checked"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Custom Settings" Name="rbtnCustomMode" IsChecked="{Binding customMode, Source={StaticResource modes}, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="customSettings_Checked"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
        <StackPanel.Style>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
              <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbtnChange}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

Another option is to use the built-in [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) converter.

```
<Grid Background="#F8FBFD">
    <Grid.Resources>
       <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackType" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,93,0,428">
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" >Installation Type</TextBlock>
                <RadioButton Checked="NewMode_Checked" Content="New " x:Name="rbtnNew" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding newMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}"/>
                <RadioButton  Checked="UpgradeMode_Checked" Content="Update" x:Name="rbtnUpgrade" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding upgradeMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}" />
                <RadioButton  Checked="ChangeMode_Checked" Content="Change" x:Name="rbtnChange" GroupName="InstallType" IsChecked="{Binding changeMode, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource modes}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackMode" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbtnChange, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16" Width="204" Height="147">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}" >Installation Mode</TextBlock>
                <RadioButton Content="Default Settings" Name="rbtnDefaultMode" IsChecked="{Binding defaultMode, Source={StaticResource modes}, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="defaultSettings_Checked"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Custom Settings" Name="rbtnCustomMode" IsChecked="{Binding customMode, Source={StaticResource modes}, Mode=TwoWay}" Checked="customSettings_Checked"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

Update for your comment about the initial state that should be `Collapsed`. You can just add another `DataTrigger` for the `IsChecked="False"` state of the `rbtnChange` `RadioButton`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbtnChange}" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbtnChange}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Of course, you could also *"invert"* the style, setting `Collapsed` as default and adding triggers for each of the other `RadioButton`s to set `Visible`, but for more buttons this would not scale well.

Comment: Doing this, the stack panel above gets hidden as well if I select `rbtnChange`. I tried doing this: `` <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbtnNew, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">``

And this seems to work but how can I do it for the `rbtnNew` and `rbtnUpdate`?

Comment: @PowershellScripter Which one gets hidden es well? Only `StackMode` will be hidden when `rbtnChange` is selected, that is also what you asked for in your question. What should `rbtnNew` and `rbtnUpdate` do instead? Your code does the same, but using a converter.

Comment: `rbtnNew` and `rbtnUpdate` should make the `StackMode` visible and `rbtnChange` should hide it. I've tried adding DataTriggers for all three radio buttons but I get the same result. If I select `rbtnChange`, both the stack panels get hidden.

Comment: @PowershellScripter The `Setter` sets the value in case the data trigger does not get triggered. That means only if `rbtnChange`s `IsChecked` property is `True`, the `Visibility` will be set to `Collapsed`. In all other cases it will be set to `Visible`. There is no need for multiple tiggers. I have tested this and it works fine. Your example with the binding converter works, too, but instead of the `StackMode` panel it hides the `materialDesign:Card`., _not_ the `StackPanel`. If that does not work, there must be another issue that is not shown in your code.

Comment: @PowershellScripter Apart from that it is still not clear which "both the stack panels" are. Do you mean `StackMode` and `StackType` or one of the unnamed nested `StackPanels` or do you actually mean the `Card`? Are there other panels that are not shown in your code? Which one should be hidden and which not? As already stated, with this code only `StackMode` (and all of its contents) will be hidden when `rbtnChange` is checked.

Comment: I think what was happening was that the unnamed stack panel was being hidden. But that's working now. It's fault on my end. Thank you very much for your explanation. I was trying to do another approach where I was adding another `public static string modeVisibility {get; set; }` and was going to set the value of Visibility based off of that. This approach is shorter and more simpler as well. Once again, thank you very much

Comment: @PowershellScripter I am glad, that it worked :-D. I have added your converter approach for completeness (but on the `StackModes` panel).

Comment: Sorry, but quick question. The converter approach hides the `StackModes` panel initially and it's only visible when the respective radio button is selected. Is there a way that I can do the same, i.e: hide the `StackModes` panel initially and have it show only when the radio buttons are selected? Currently, with the Data Triggers, it's visible when you haven't selected a value initially as well.

Comment: @PowershellScripter Updated the answer. You just add a `DataTrigger` for the `False` state.